# Set source of IP packets, when multihomed setup on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

I set up FreeBSD as router and I have 2 ISP available. I set up IPs from both ISPs (let's call it IP1 and IP2; behind these IPs there'll be GW1 and GW2) on `igb0` and `igb1`, added default gw to GW1, and now I can see the internet, but (surely) can't reach the IP2 from outside.

Now I need to set up that IP1 and IP2 are reachable from the world, it the respective link is up.

**Do I have any easy option to do that beside deal with any firewall rules?** Can't figure out the easiest way to accomplish my goal.

Comment: Probably the firewall rules don't permit 'new' traffic into the router. That's generally the default. The only other possibility is permt all 'new' traffic, which would be chaos! If you want to get in from the outside, th

Comment: Forget the above comment. I can't delete it.

Comment: Please edit your post to show the command you're using that makes you think you can't reach IP1 and/or IP2 from the outside.  Also, please indicate where are you doing the "outside" testing from.

Answer (score 0):

The default firewall rules won't allow 'new' traffic from the outside. You can open certain ports, which correspond to certain server protocols, and permit new incoming traffic on those.

21 ftp
80, 81, 443, 8080 http
23 telnet

Here's the full list:

[IP Port Assignments](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)